# Skip custom Field if not exsist?

Tags: wordpress

i have a code like this, to display a custom field on my Page...

```
<?php 
   global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;           
        if($immopress_property['assistedLiving']): ?>

           <li class="assistedLiving">
              <span class="attribute"  style="width:200px;display:block;float:left;"><?php echo 'Seniorengerechtes Wohnen' ; ?><span class="wpp_colon">:</span></span>
              <span class="value"><?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving' , true)) echo "Ja"; else echo "Nein"; ?>&nbsp;</span>
           </li>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

But when the custom field `NAME` & `VALUE` not exist it shall skip to the next Value and Name. I try different ways to do that but no one works.

Hope someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

changed to this and it works...

if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assistedLiving', true) ) { ?>